# How a checker tool execution happens if make C=1 or make C=2 is done in linux kernel?

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, static-analysis

How a checker tool is executed along with compilation of linux kernel code when make C=1 is executed?

In Detail : make C=1   [targets] Check all c source with checker tool. By default checker tool is "sparse". so here my query is, how checker tool will be executed along with compilation of C source? (I am unable to get same information from Makefile of linux kernel).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile executes the checker tool in same way it executes the compiler.

Search for `checksrc` in `scripts/Makefile.build`.

Comment: I am able to check out information given by you. But Still i am not clear. For example take one file kernel/fork.c. Are both commands gcc <all_options> kernel/fork.c and sparse <all_options> kernel/fork.c executed one after other (or) is there any single statement in linux/Makefile that executes sparse along with gcc. ( Here sparse can be referenced as a checker tool ). If we want to implement same logic in our own makefile how can we do that?

Comment: And what do you not understand about the calls of the `cmd_(force_)checksrc` macros?

Comment: I checked cmd_force_checksrc that it has checker tool command with options. but my doubt was regarding execution. now I am clear with this. I executed make C=2 V=1. checked make verbose. After analyzing the verbose I understood that sparse is executed on c sources first then gcc is executed on the c sources.